# I'd like to migrate my question to crypto.SE

Tags: support, migration, specific-question

Hi friendly moderators,

I'd like to migrate [my question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/60699/9643) to crypto.SE because I believe it would be a better fit there (even though it has an accepted answer). Unfortunately, I don't have enough super powers to do that myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To contact moderators about a post, use the “flag” button under that post.

In this specific case, I don't see a reason to migrate. The question is on-topic here. In fact, it's arguably more on-topic here than on Crypto, since it's about security properties related to information flow, and not about how cryptography works. Furthermore the question has had a satisfactory answer. We would only migrate a question away if it was off-topic, or at least if it was borderline, more off-topic elsewhere and unlikely to be satisfactorily answered here. These conditions do not apply.